# Adding a border in HTML

Tags: html

Any thoughts as to why this isn't working?

```
      <tr style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px; border-color: #97298f;">
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is more detail from this section, applying to cells since it wasn't working for the row, using the suggestions below – but it's still not working:

```
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 0px 0px 3px 0px solid #97298f" width="75%" colspan="3"><p><i><span style="font-size:42pt;font-family:"Fira Sans Medium",sans-serif; color:#7030A0">Joining Together</span></i></p></td>
        <td style="border: 0px 0px 3px 0px solid #97298f" width="25%"><p align="right" style="text-align:right"><span style="font-family:"Fira Sans Light",sans-serif;"><img width=112 height=62 src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1ZVLVDqtRqX691OXo7dN2n1Pb2V1D42Lq&authuser=camfont%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs"
  alt="Unity Logo" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_4"></span></p></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of the border attribute are in the following order:
border-width, border-style and then the color.

Take a look at this example

```
<tr style="border: 1px solid red;">
```

You can open [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) site to know more abbout styling tables.

Comment: Ok I just tried

```
<tr style="border: 0px 0px 3px 0px solid #97298f">
```

But it didn't work...

Comment: You just want a border in the bottom? Use ```border-bottom: 3px solid #97298f```. Just add the position you want after the ```border-```, you can use: top, right, left and bottom.